# Run time Error:3086 Could not delete from Specified table. in MS-Access vba code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, runtime-error, sql-delete

I am trying to delete specific rows using following code in MS-ACCESS. I have created a form using VBA and using this code

```
Dim dbs As Database
Dim MyDate
MyDate = Date
Set dbs = CurrentDb

If IsNull(Me.Text72.Value) Then
MsgBox "Values are Missing"
Else
'dbs.Execute "insert into scott_synonym_cidm (id,synonym_cidm,source,status,username,updatedate) values ( '" & Me.id.Value & "' ,'" & Me.syn_name.Value & "','" & Me.system.Value & "','YES','" & Me.Text72.Value & "','" & MyDate & "')"
'MsgBox "Record Inserted "

dbs.Execute "delete  from scott_unmatched where tradename =  '300MM SODIUM CARBONATE' "
MsgBox "Record deleted "
End If
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

When I am running this the row is inserted in the table but gives error when delete statement is executed.

The tables have connection from Oracle.

Comment: Make sure the ODBC connection is not _Read only_. Also, why do you have an *Excel* tag, where is excel in the system?

Comment: An other option: when comparing strings, you'd better make sure there are no white spaces. Use [Trim()](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/trim.php): `where Trim(tradename) =  '300MM SODIUM CARBONATE'`

Comment: Hey Thank you `@marlan`.  Can you please tell me how to check that "ODBC connection is  Read only". But, I am able to insert the record into the table is it possible to insert a record when its "Read only" connection?

Comment: Confirm - can you manually delete the row in the table view from Access?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, but with SQL. I can debug.print the sql string for the delete statement, and I can run it in SSMS, but when I attempt to run it from the access vba, I get this error. I have confirmed that my account has write rights, and I can use vba to add a record to the same table without error.